# GraphQL + Relay: How can I perform authorization for refetching?

Tags: express, graphql, relay

I am working on a GraphQL server built using Express and attempting to support Relay.

For a regular GraphQL query, I can handle authorization in the resolve function. E.g.:

```
var queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: () => ({
        foo: {
            type: new GraphQLList(bar),
            description: 'I should have access to some but not all instances of bar',
            resolve: (root, args, request) => getBarsIHaveAccessTo(request.user)
        }
    })
});
```

To support Relay refetching on the back-end, Facebook's Relay tutorial instructs us to have GraphQL objects implement a nodeInterface for mapping global ids to objects and objects to GraphQL types. The nodeInterface is defined by the nodeDefinitions function from [graphql-relay](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js).

```
const {nodeInterface, nodeField} = nodeDefinitions(
    (globalId) => {
        const {type, id} = fromGlobalId(globalId);
        if (type === 'bar') {
            // since I don't have access to the request object here, I can't pass the user to getBar, so getBar can't perform authorization
            return getBar(id);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    },
    (obj) => {
        // return the object type
    }
);
```

The refetching function that gets passed to nodeDefinitions doesn't get passed the request object, only the global id. How can I get access to the user during refetching so I can authorize those requests?

As a sanity check, I tried querying for nodes that the authenticated user doesn't otherwise have access to (and shouldn't) through the node interface, and got the requested data back:

```
{node(id:"id_of_something_unauthorized"){
    ... on bar {
        field_this_user_shouldnt_see
    }
}}
```

=>

```
{
    "data": {
        "node": {
            "field_this_user_shouldnt_see": "a secret"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the request data actually does get passed to resolve. If we look at the source, we see that `nodeDefinitions` tosses out the `parent` parameter and passes the global `id`, the `context` (containing the request data), and the `info` arguments from `nodeField`'s resolve function.

Ultimately, where a `resolve` call would get the following arguments:

```
(parent, args, context, info)
```

the `idFetcher` instead gets:

```
(id, context, info)
```

So we can implement authorization as follows:

```
const {nodeInterface, nodeField} = nodeDefinitions(
    (globalId, context) => {
        const {type, id} = fromGlobalId(globalId);
        if (type === 'bar') {
            // get Bar with id==id if context.user has access
            return getBar(context.user, id);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    },
    (obj) => {
        // return the object type
    }
);
```

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/master/src/node/node.js#L94-L102